# Problem with USB CDC settings and libraries for STM32F4

Tags: c, usb, cdc, stm32f4

I'm working in an embedded aplication for `STM32F401RBT6` and I'm trying to establish a connection with the PC (Windows 10) but the device is not recognized by the system. The code that I generated by `STMCubeMX` and debugged by `Atollic` not works. I saw and try reproduce several examples, but anything works. In the code, I have all libraries that **i think** necessary.

[image: archives]
[image: archives2]

I'm have this archives generated by `STMCubeMX` for the `CDC` comunication, but I'm newbie and I don't know what I have to modify on the code for the USB be recognized by the system. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside the point from Soup ( the failing malloc caused by a heap that is only 0x200 by default) some Windows version have a problem with the line coding in the example.

In the usbd_cdc_if.c you should add:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN PRIVATE_VARIABLES */
USBD_CDC_LineCodingTypeDef LineCoding =
    {
    115200, /* baud rate*/
    0x00,   /* stop bits-1*/
    0x00,   /* parity - none*/
    0x08    /* nb. of bits 8*/
    };
```

And a little bit below

```
static int8_t CDC_Control_FS(uint8_t cmd, uint8_t* pbuf, uint16_t length)
.
.
.
case CDC_SET_LINE_CODING:
    LineCoding.bitrate    = (uint32_t)(pbuf[0] | (pbuf[1] << 8) |\
                            (pbuf[2] << 16) | (pbuf[3] << 24));
    LineCoding.format     = pbuf[4];
    LineCoding.paritytype = pbuf[5];
    LineCoding.datatype   = pbuf[6];

break;

case CDC_GET_LINE_CODING:
    pbuf[0] = (uint8_t)(LineCoding.bitrate);
    pbuf[1] = (uint8_t)(LineCoding.bitrate >> 8);
    pbuf[2] = (uint8_t)(LineCoding.bitrate >> 16);
    pbuf[3] = (uint8_t)(LineCoding.bitrate >> 24);
    pbuf[4] = LineCoding.format;
    pbuf[5] = LineCoding.paritytype;
    pbuf[6] = LineCoding.datatype;
break;
```

So the host won't get undefined data if he tries to set the line coding.

Answer (score 0):

Inside USBD_CDC_Init(..) function there is a malloc function which allocates about 540 Bytes memory on the Heap.

This was not taken into account from CubeMX when code generated .

So , at least you must define the Heap size taking into account theese extra Bytes,  to have the USB CDC port working.